# How to perform likelihood ratio test on logistic regression in SAS?

Tags: sas, regression

I want to perform the standard likelihood ratio test in logsitic regression using SAS. I will have a full logistic model, containing all variables, named A and a nested logistic model B, which is derived by dropping out one variable from A.

If I want to test whether that drop out variable is significant or not, I shall perform a likelihood ratio test of model A and B. Is there an easy way to perform this test (essentially a chi-square test) in SAS using a PROC? Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to perform likelihood ratio tests that are full model v.s. one variable dropped model, you can use the GENMOD procedure with the type3 option.

Script:

```
data d1;
do z = 0 to 2;
do y = 0 to 1;
do x = 0 to 1;
  input n @@;
  output;
end; end; end;
cards;
100 200 300 400
50 100 150 200
50 100 150 200
;
proc genmod data = d1;
  class y z;
  freq n;
  model x = y z / error = bin link = logit type3;
run;
```

Output:

```
     LR Statistics For Type 3 Analysis

                          Chi-
Source           DF     Square    Pr > ChiSq

y                 1      16.09        <.0001
z                 2       0.00        1.0000
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about a PROC statement that can specifically perform LRT but you can compute the test for nested models.

Script

```
proc logistic data = full_model;
model dependent_var = independent_var(s);
ods output GlobalTests = GlobalTests_full;
run;

data _null_;
set GlobalTests_full;
if test = "Likelihood Ratio" then do;
   call symput("ChiSq_full", ChiSq);
   call symput("DF_full", DF);
   end;
run;

proc logistic data = reduced_model;
model dependent_var = independent_var(s);
ods output GlobalTests = GlobalTests_reduced;
run;

data _null_;
set GlobalTests_reduced;
if test = "Likelihood Ratio" then do;
   call symput("ChiSq_reduced", ChiSq);
   call symput("DF_reduced", DF);
   end;
run;

data LRT_result;
LR = &ChiSq_full - &ChiSq_reduced;
DF = &DF_full - &DF_reduced;
p = 1 - probchi(ChiSq,DF);
run;
```

Comment: Why create the macro variables?  You should just combine the two datasets directly.

Comment: Without the macro variable, how to identify the full and reduced model to compute their LR.

Comment: Use the RENAME= dataset option.

Comment: I think I found a typo. Shouldn't it be `proc logistic` (not `ligistic`)?

Comment: @Chernoff Thanks for pointing out the typo. I have edited the post now.

Comment: Also look here [link](https://support.sas.com/kb/24/449.html) and here [link](https://support.sas.com/kb/42/514.html) (can be found from the previous link). Links to SAS solutions if we speaks about models comparison

Comment: Hi! I wondered in proc surveylogistic, how can I get the degree of freedom for LRT?

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on logistic regression, but I think what you are trying to accomplish can be done with PROC LOGISTIC, using the "SELECTION=SCORE" option on the MODEL statement.  There are other SELECTION options available, such as STEPWISE, but I think SCORE matches closest to what you are looking for.  I would suggest reading up on it though, because there are some associated options (BEST=, START= STOP=) that you might benefit from too.

Comment: The SELECTION=SCORE is actually the best subset automatic feature selection config. It is not exactly what I am looking for. I want to know whether there are some PROC in SAS that can help me perform likelihood ratio test of two existing models (one nested another). But thank you very much for the contribution. Appreciate it.