# How to compare two models in SAS (complex survey design)

Tags: sas

I have two models to compare. The full model has an interaction term while the reduced model doesn't. I am using the likelihood ratio test to compare two models and generate a p-value to report.

I found the script here is very helpful. [How to perform likelihood ratio test on logistic regression in SAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734495/how-to-perform-likelihood-ratio-test-on-logistic-regression-in-sas)

But I had a question when I tried it in my own dataset. The dataset is from a complex survey and requires `proc survey*`. I don't know where to find the **degree of freedom** because in the `proc surveylogistic`, the global test has a denominator DF and a numerator DF and they are corrected by the Rao-Scott test.

In the SAS document [here](https://support.sas.com/kb/24/474.html), I found that

> The LRT statistic has an approximate chi-square distribution with degrees of freedom equal to the difference in the number of parameters between the full and reduced models.

I just don't know whether I should use the DF(corrected by Rao-Scott test) or the difference in the number of parameters, which can be calculated from the DF of Wald tests.

I had another question about the [SAS document](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.3/statug/statug_surveylogistic_details40.htm#statug.surveylogistic.surveylogistictlh):

> As the denominator degrees of freedom grows, an *F* distribution approaches a chi-square distribution, and similarly a *t* distribution approaches a normal distribution.

Does that mean I need to calculate the *p* by `p=1-probf(LR,ndf,ddf)` rather than `probchi`?

I messed up with the degree of freedom. I tried all these and it returns different ps. I just wondered which one is the correct one. Is there a smart way to compare models in SAS with the `proc survey*`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

https://communities.sas.com/t5/Statistical-Procedures/Degree-of-freedom-in-proc-surveylogistic/m-p/803329/emcs_t/S2h8ZW1haWx8dG9waWNfc3Vic2NyaXB0aW9ufEwxMjUySFFHUTlPSzY2fDgwMzMyOXxTVUJTQ1JJUFRJT05TfGhL#M39485

Credit to SAS_Rob from SAS help community:
If you add the `DF=INFINITY` option to the MODEL statement in Proc SURVEYLOGISTIC then the Global tests, including the LRT, will be tested using a Chi-Square distribution.  You could then use a similar approach to your example to compute an overall LRT for the full versus reduced model.

I tried and it worked. It turned out that the DF is the Numerator DF without `DF=INFINITY` statement.